# How to disable browser history saving or cashing option from ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I have used following code to set HTTP header 
**Pragma : no-cache** And **Cache-Control : no-cache, no-control**

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

I checked response header contains Pragma: no-cache that means above C# code is working fine.

My question is;

Application response header contains Pragma: no-cache and Cache-Control: no-chase. Then why browse saving the history?

I need help how I can disable back button or saving history by browser.

I know I can hide tool bar from browser by js and also can disable back button functionality by writing js code but I need another solution.

Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache has nothing to do with history.  These are two different functions. Disabling cacheing does not instruct the browser to avoid saving history.  There is no supported way to "disable the back button" or disable history.

This is a client feature. There may or may not be certain browser specific hacks you could do, but these are unsupported and will likely break with newer versions of browsers, mobile browsers, etc...

Instead of trying to force the browser to do something it wasn't designed to do, design your site so the back button doesn't cause problems.

For instance, use the Post Redirect Get pattern to help mitigate reposting data.

I refuse to use any site that messes with my browser in this manner (I may have other history that I want to keep, and if you go deleting it on me without my permission, I will be very angry).  I know many other people that feel the same.  So unless you want to alienate your users, don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

Have this in your code, Controller action will work even when you hit browser back button -

```
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "private"); // HTTP 1.1
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); // HTTP 1.1
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "max-stale=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "pre-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1 
Response.AppendHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=3, max=993"); // HTTP 1.1 
Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // HTTP 1.1
```

**UPDATE**

I used this in the controller action as shown below, when I hit browser back button I got controller action breakpoint hit. I am using Chrome 33.0.1750.117 to test.

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "private"); // HTTP 1.1
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store"); // HTTP 1.1
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "max-stale=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "pre-check=0"); // HTTP 1.1 
        Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1 
        Response.AppendHeader("Keep-Alive", "timeout=3, max=993"); // HTTP 1.1 
        Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // HTTP 1.1
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry; I have tried but no luck. Is it possible to share any sample project? Thanks for response.

Comment: For caching it is Ok and thanks. Is there any way to stop history saving in browser? I want if user press back button then it will stay same page.. Is it possible?

Comment: @Hasibul, You can try JavaScript history.forward(). But I am not sure about its behaviour in different browser. But give it a try - http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/