# How to remove specfic history record after auto rediret in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, view, rdlc

My question is that
when i submit the form from index view where i'm selecting the some
record and send to the controller and move on the next view
Here is my Code

```
@using ReportViewerForMvc;    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "/FOO/Login/Home";
        }, 300000);
    });  
</script>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Report Viewer";
}  

@Html.ReportViewer(ViewBag.ReportViewer as Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer)
```

at this view after applying condition the page is redirect on Home page successfully but
when end user click on the back button in browser its show the same report with
result

How it can handle the previous record when back button is press
or not save the history in browser cookie or cache

Comment: Maybe look to disable the back button. Allowing re-submission of data in your site is a potentially dangerous issue.

Comment: i can not disable the browser back button it's requirement to enable the button and not move again to previous reports

Comment: Could you store the current report id/name is session. Then when the controller handles the request, check to see if the report to be processed is the same as the one is session.

Comment: @Wheels73  but the user can see report from index view as much time that  the end user want 
in you condition the user cannot see the report

Comment: Have a read of this...I dont this you can acheive what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21953384/how-to-disable-browser-history-saving-or-cashing-option-from-asp-net-mvc

Comment: How do you loading this view? from a controller action method?

Comment: If you are loading this view from a actionmethod then add this `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 1)]` attribute at your actionmethod/controller.

Comment: @mmushtaq get the parameter form index post method and passes to the next action method this its view as mention in question
and  also
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 1)] this not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot remove the entire back button history. All you can do is replace the last entry with the next page, using `window.location.replace('url');`

Or You can disable the back button using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = window.history.forward(0);
</script>
```